# Retrofit 2 adding new line character at the end of header string

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit v2.4, It is adding a new line character in headers which fails my call

"Authorization: Base dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=\n"

What is solution for this?

Comment: share code for your `retrofit call` and `interface`

Comment: @Sam did you solve this issue? I've experienced the same one

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that implements `okhttp3.Interceptor` and override `intercept()` and do whatever you desire to the headers, both outgoing or incoming:

```
@Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request initialReq = chain.request();
        Headers outgoingHeaders = initialRequest.headers()
        ...
        Request modRequest = initialReq.newBuilder()
              .addHeader(...);

        Response response = chain.proceed(modRequest);
        Headers incomingHeaders = response.headers();
        ...
        return response;
}
```

And dont forget to add it to the httpclient:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            ...
            .addInterceptor(headersInterceptor)
            .build();
```